# conversion to '...' from int may change the sign of the result

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
        std::array<std::string, 1> xx{"hello"};
        int x = 0;
        std::cout << xx[x] << std::endl;
}
```

Выдает предупреждение:

```
qwer.cpp:8:18: warning: conversion to ‘std::array<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, 1>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} from ‘int’ may change the sign of the result [-Wsign-conversion]
    8 |  std::cout << xx[x] << std::endl;
      |                  ^
```

Что это означает?

Answer (score 1):

У класса `array` перегруженный оператор [] принимает в качестве параметра `size_type`, который является псевдонимом беззнакового целочисленного типа `long unsigned int`. Вы же, в свою очередь, передаёте ему переменную `x`, имеющую знаковый тип `int`. Вот компилятор и предупреждает, дескать, а вдруг в `x` записано отрицательное число, и это преобразование `int` в `size_type` поменяет знак результата.